# Can a local UDK server have two clients connected locally?

Tags: networking, udk

To do some basic testing on players interacting with other players I would need to have at least two players in my world. My solution is to run the server from my computer, then run two clients. When I run the second client and connect to the server, I find a weapon dropped by client 1 in the appropriate position(but no body). What happened?

server.bat:
C:\UDK\UDK-2015-01\Binaries\Win32\UDK.exe server ieTestMap?GoalScore=0?TimeLimit=0?Game=ie.ieGame  -log

client.bat:
C:\UDK\UDK-2015-01\Binaries\Win32\UDK.exe 127.0.0.1 -log

```
class ieGame extends UTDeathmatch;

simulated function PostBeginPlay()
{
}
defaultproperties
{
    bScoreDeaths=false
    PlayerControllerClass=class'ie.iePlayerController'
    DefaultPawnClass=class'ie.iePawn'

    bDelayedStart=false
    GameReplicationInfoClass=class'ie.ieGameReplicationInfo'
}

class iePlayerController extends UTPlayerController;
reliable client function ClientSetHUD(class<HUD> newHUDType)
{
    if(myHUD != none)
        myHUD.Destroy();

    myHUD = spawn(class'ieHUD', self);
}
defaultproperties
{
}
```

I have kept the other classes of my game 'bare-bone.'